# Sending a HTTP Post Request correctly

Tags: java, http, aws-lambda, forms, http-post

I have a simple AWS Lambda function that must receive HTTP Post data and print it:

***AWS Lambda function***

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var ses = new aws.SES();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log("Incoming: ", event);             
};
```

***My HTML form:***

```
<form action="http://myawsfuncurl" method="POST">
   <input type="textarea" width="200" height="100" value="Hello"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

**The console simply prints: Incoming: {}**
No data is received.

However, this works fine when i send HTTP Post via a java code:

***Java Code***

```
URL obj = new URL("http://myawsfuncurl");
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
//add reuqest header
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

String payload = "hello";

// Send post request
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(payload);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

**How can i make it work via HTML form too?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to send it via http POST form.

I got around this by sending it via an Ajax request which sends JSON data to the function.

Something like this should hopefully help. If you put it in a script tag on your html page.

```
<script>
    $.support.cors = true;
    $('#id_of_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();         
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://myawsfuncurl',                 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    ParamA: $('#id_of_textarea").text()                 
                },
                error: function(obj, msg, exc){},
                success: function(data){
                   alert('complete');                       
                }
            }
        )

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Darren> Sorry i got round to trying this only now... i get this error now:  No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.mywebsite.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: Yeah, you will need to allow it to go through. Did you add the line $.support.cors = true; This, if I remember rightly, made it work. If not you can do something with JSONP as the data type. Or depending on the implementation you can hide it behind your website. For example if you are using MVC you can create a controller and make the request to the AWS Function Url instead.

Comment: Darren> Yes i have added $.support.cors = true (did not help), i have also tried using JSONP (apparently it can't be used with POST request). Going server route is cumbersome for me.... I read somewhere AWS Javascript SDK will help - but i haven't tried and i am reluctant to add yet another js sdk to webpage. Could you please look up your implementation to see how that works for you?

Comment: So we actually went a slightly different route. We used API Gateway in front of the AWS Lambda function. This then allows you to setup the CORS capability which you will need. This [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) will help you set it up correctly. This basically will act as your API server and allow you to interact with the function correctly. You basically need to mock the OPTIONS verbs to return a healthy OK message back and I think it got it working.