# AWS what is the simplest way to send email in a specific time with an attachment

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, scheduled-tasks

I want to do a `Task Scheduler` that sends notifications via email at a specific time, for example: every day at 12:00.

I found some solutions that requires code to achieve it, such as: Lambda, Poweshell, cron jobs, etc. But all those solutions are too complicated.

Is there any other way achieving this?

I found `SES, SNS, SQS` but couldn't find how to set a specific time to send the notification/emails.

Can you help me find the simplest tool for that (prefer without any code needed)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's probably 2 questions in your message but honestly lambda will not be too complicated to setup.

1) **Send email from Amazon platform**:

you mention SNS, SES and SQS so lets look:

- SNS : Amazon Simple Notification Service

Send mobile notifications, emails and/or SMS messages. In your case (email) as its notification based you need the subscriber to specify email as the protocol of receiving notification. Probably not what you're looking for

- SES : Amazon Simple Email Service

With Amazon SES, you can send transactional email, marketing messages, or any other type of high-quality content to your customers. Probably what you're looking for

- SQS : Amazon Simple Queue Service

Store data for future processing in a queue. The lingo for this is storing "messages" but it doesn't have anything to do with email or SMS. SQS doesn't have any logic, it's just a place to put things and take things out. (from https://www.expeditedssl.com/aws-in-plain-english).

Look at his [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608503/sending-email-via-aws-ses-within-aws-lambda-function) with the question and answer you'll have a fully setup lambda to send email from AWS lambda using SES

2) **Schedule the lambda to run at specific time**

Back in [october 2015](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/) Amazon introduced Scheduled Functions (Cron) so

> You can now invoke a Lambda function on a regular, scheduled basis.
>   You can specify a fixed rate (number of minutes, hours, or days
>   between invocations) or you can specify a Cron-like expression:

[image]